# How to search values in table in Mysql Workbench?

Tags: search, mysql-workbench

I am using Mysql Workbench v 5.2.47 CE.

I cannot find any option to search in a db table using GUI.
In phpMyAdmin, there is a Search button, that shows form with all table columns, so I can filter the search results according value in some columns. IS there any alternative in Workbench?

I really cannot find it and programme Help hints didn't help me.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the new 6.0 release we added a search feature that should do what you want. So upgrade and then start the search wizard via Database -> Search Table Data.

Comment: Thanks. Possibilities for search are just basic. It is not possible to filter search on specific column or search for more values in more columns, but is ok for now.

Comment: Tomas, for further ideas to improve this feature please file feature requests at http://bugs.mysql.com.